# Migrate PV and change CPU limits on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, ansible-awx

I have a small kubernetes cluster with AWX running.
I would like to make some changes, the PV is a filesystem on one of the nodes.
Is it possible to migrate it to a different PV, like NFS?

Also, I would like to change the CPU and memory limits. But I guess I will have to redeploy it.

Should I try to migrate the PV or delete everything and recreate it?

Thanks

Comment: Create another PV, attach both and in `initContainer` rsync data from one to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have dynamic provisioning enabled I advice you to use [pv-migrate](https://github.com/utkuozdemir/pv-migrate).

This is a cli tool/kubectl plugin to easily migrate the contents of one Kubernetes  `PersistentVolume`  to another.

Common use cases:

1. You have a database with a bound 30 GB `PersistentVolumeClaim`. It occurred 30 GB was not enough and you filled all the disk space rather quickly. And sadly your `StorageClass`/provisioner doesn't support  [volume expansion](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/). Now you need to create a new PVC of 100 GB and somehow copy all the data to the new volume, as-is, with its permissions and so on.
2. You need to move a `PersistentVolumeClaim` from one namespace to another.

To migrate contents of `PersistentVolumeClaim` pvc-a in namespace name-space-a to the `PersistentVolumeClaim` pvc-b in namespace name-space-b, use the following command:

```
$ kubectl pv-migrate \
  --source-namespace name-space-a \
  --source pvc-a \
  --dest-namespace name-space-b \
  --dest pvc-b
```

Take also a look at: [change-pv-reclaim-policy](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/change-pv-reclaim-policy/), [resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/07/12/resizing-persistent-volumes-using-kubernetes/).